# Android - Worklight Hybrid application fails to connect to server in the emulator

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a worklight application. I tried running that application on android emulator and i am getting the following error.

```
   [http://localhost:8080/apps/services/api/MyFirstApp/android/query] Host is not responsive.
    Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity
```

So i tried to enter the same url in the emulator browser, i got the following text:

```
  /*-secure-
  {"WL-Authentication-Failure": {"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"reason":"Login Failed}}} */
```

Can someone help me with this?

I am using Android OS version: 4.2.2, API level: 17

I haven't changed any application settings myself.. 
I am trying to go to a basic login page with the url "https://jazz.net/jazz/auth/j_security_check"

This is my adapter XML:

```
<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="worklight.com/integration"; xmlns:http="worklight.com/integration/http"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; name="RQMAdapter">
    <displayName>RQMAdapter</displayName> 
    <description>HTTP type Worklight Adapter for jazz server</description>
    <connectivity> 
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol> 
            <domain>jazz.net</domain>
            </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" /> 
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="loginToRQM" />
</wl:adapter>
```

This is my scenario:
I have a requirement where I need to read information about the projects from jazz.net for a user. They are all available on the jazz server within an XML file. I need to process it to a mobile device to make it available on hand held device... So, now I am told that i will have to download some of the files from the server, so i need to have file IO on my app. I learned that we need to write this part using a Cordova plug-in in Worklight.

please let me know what else is needed for the solution... thank you

Comment: Please edit your post with more information: Android OS version, steps to reproduction, if you have changed the application settings in any way (authenticationConfig.xml for example, securityTests, etc...).

Comment: Also mention what is your Worklight version used, and what is your Android API Level that you have installed via the Android SDK Mananger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to place the actual IP address of your server machine:

1. Change the value for `worklightServerRootURL` in the file
   application-descriptor.xml (located at: yourProject\apps\yourApp)
2. Build and deploy
3. Right-click on the generated Android project >> Run As >> Run application

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have tried that too.. doesnt work :( and do you have any idea how i can call an android class function from the worklight project ?

Comment: That would be a separate question, open a new question.

Comment: Quote in your original question the authenticationConfig.xml file from your project (resides under server\conf).

Comment: i cant post my file because its too long, hence the website doesnt allow me to do so ..

Comment: <worklightServerRootURL>http://${local.IPAddress}:8080/</worklightServerRootURL> this is how i am getting the root server url.. is there something wrong in the URL ?

Comment: Well, yes, in my Answer I suggest place instead of local.IPAddress the actual IP address that is assigned to your computer. You can find it via a command window and the command ipconfig.

Comment: i already tried that before posting my question . but it gives me the same result..

Comment: Then please follow my comment above for the question. this might be some configuration issue.

Comment: i am also getting the following error.. i dont know if this relates to this issue.. 
file:///data/data/com.RQMLight/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js: Line 1092 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 Utils643387773 N

i am very new to worklight and this is an existing project, so pls excuse my ignorance..

Comment: It will help if you will answer the questions asked... :) again, see my question in the comments section of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using using Worklight 5.0.5, make sure to upgrade to 5.0.6, where a fix is available when only API Level 17 is installed.

As for going to that URL, you need to explain where exactly you're trying to go to it from, and how... you need to be more descriptive. It sounds to me like you haven't gone through the Getting Started material. [Please do](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

Comment: I am using a HTTPAdapter to get to the url. I have given the domain name to be jazz.net, protocol : https, and im appending the rest of the url in the impl.js .. is this what you were asking about ?

Comment: <wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
 xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 name="RQMAdapter">

 <displayName>RQMAdapter</displayName>
 <description>HTTP type Worklight Adapter for jazz server</description>
 <connectivity>
  <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <domain>jazz.net</domain>
  </connectionPolicy>
  <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
 </connectivity>
 <procedure name="loginToRQM" />
</wl:adapter>

Comment: Is jazz HTTP or HTTPS? You also need to specify a PORT number. Please read the http adapter training module: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf

Comment: it is https only.. i havent given any port number here, it works for me in browser simulator though..

Comment: i dont have any port number of that url. i m getting "connection refused" if i give 8080

Comment: I can't help you any further until you fully explain what it is you are trying to do. Full scenario and use case.

Comment: Here is the scenario.I am working on a POC. 
I have a requirement where I need to read information about the projects from jazz.net for a user. They are all available on the jazz server within an xml file. I need to process it to a mobile device to make it available on hand held device.. 
So, now i am told that i wil have to download some of the files from the server, so i need to have file IO on my app. I learnt that we need to write tat code in native part of the worklight project.
I am given only this much of information as of now, so i can share only this..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have solved it by using the real IP address of the server in the WL app instead of using localhost:

1. When the emulator is running your app, press the Menu button.
2. Select to change your server URL
3. Remove "localhost" and use the IP address.
4. Accept and try again.

This fixed my problem.